# Не могу запустить crystal

Tags: linux, fedora, crystal

Все делал по официальной документации [доки](http://crystal-lang.org/docs)

```
sudo dnf install crystal
```

Выдает:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:47:36 ago on Thu May  5 22:13:54 2016.    
Package crystal-0.15.0-1.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.   
Dependencies resolved.    
Nothing to do.   
Complete!
```

Но при попытке запустить файл через него, выдает `bash: crystal: command not found`

В чем проблема?

Comment: А какая у вас версия дистрибутива?

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос список файлов этого пакета (`rpm -ql crystal`).

Comment: package crystal is not installed

Comment: версия fedora 23

Comment: @Iisusyoumom, *package crystal is not installed* — это был ответ мне? ну, тогда введите более полное название пакета — как у вас в вопросе: `crystal-0.15.0-1.x86_64`. // врочем, если пакет собирала та же команда … гхм … программистов, что и для debian-а, то скрипт `crystal`, скорее всего, находится в `/opt/crystal/bin`. вот попробуйте его и запустить.

Answer (score 3):

> Package crystal-0.15.0-1.x86_64 is already installed

судя по этой информации, у вас уже установлен пакет http://dist.crystal-lang.org/rpm/crystal-0.15.0-1.x86_64.rpm

после установки этого пакета в каталоге `/opt/crystal/bin/` должен появиться скрипт `crystal`, который, вероятно, вам и нужен. запустить его можно, указав полный путь к нему:

```
/opt/crystal/bin/crystal опции параметры ...
```

для того, чтобы можно было запускать этот скрипт просто по имени, не указывая полный путь к нему, следует добавить этот путь к значению, хранящемуся в переменной окружения `PATH`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/crystal/bin"
```

чтобы не выполнять эту команду вручную в каждом экземпляре *shell*-а, можно добавить её в конец конфигурационного файла вашего *shell*-а, который называется `~/.имяrc`. узнать имя *shell*-а можно так:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

значит, файл, в который можно добавить команду: `~/.bashrc`.